# How can I import an excel column into wordpress database?

Tags: php, database

I have an excel column with around 1000 values, i need to import all these values into  my wordpress database so i can create a small form with a text input and a submit button to let the users to add an input value and check if it exists in the imported values from the database.

What is the best way to do this, do i have to create a new table for this column or should i add it to an existing table?

Answer (score 2):

There is some way to import excel to WordPress database. but I have an easy solution to import this file.

1. Go to [convertcsv.com](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm) and convert your excel file to JSON.
2. Create the below files and folders:

**Folder:** `wp-content/plugins/import/`

**File:** `wp-content/plugins/import/import.json`

**File:** `wp-content/plugins/import/import.php`

3. Then save JSON file to import.json
4. Put below code in import.php

.

```
/*
* Plugin Name: Import
* Plugin URI: https://veronalabs.com
* Description: Import excel data to WordPress
* Author: Mostafa Soufi
* Version: 1.0
* Author URI: https://mostafa-soufi.ir
*/

if ( isset( $_GET['do'] ) and $_GET['do'] == 'import' ) {
    $json = file_get_contents( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/import.json' );

    if ( $json ) {
        $data = json_decode( $json, true );

        // Print your data
        echo '<pre>' . print_r( $data, 1 ) . '</pre>';

        // Each data
        foreach ( $data as $item ) {
            // Create post object
            $args = array(
                'post_title'   => $item['title'], // your column
                'post_content' => $item['content'], // your column
                'post_status'  => 'publish',
                'post_type'    => 'post',
                'post_author'  => 1
            );

            // Insert the post into the database
            //$post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );
        }
    }

    exit;
}
```

5. Go to Plugins and enable Import plugin. then run this request in your WordPress:

   http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/?do=import

Don't forget, you should get valid data from your json. You can see this data through `print_r` before each data.

Comment: @tarek Do you check that?

Comment: First thanks for your answer, but is this will create a post for each value in the column?

Comment: Each row in the excel creating a post.

Comment: What if i had 100,000 rows, is there another method to import this data one time without creating post for each row?

Comment: It's possible. What do you need exactly?

Comment: I need to import these values into my wordpress database so i can create a small form with a text input and a submit button to let the users add an input value and check if it exists in the imported values from the database (I need to let the users validate the code they entered with the database)

Comment: Send your table information with all columns.